# don't work 'fadeOut' If there is 'replaceWith'.?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When i use of `fadeOut` and `replaceWith` together, does not work fadeOut. but if i use only of `fadeOut` it worked. i want use of each tow they together. how is it in my code?

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        success: function(html){
            var $html = $(html);
////////////////////////////////// here ////////////////////////////////
                    $('.ser_form #paginate input:checkbox:checked').parent().parent().fadeOut("slow");

                    $('#num_count').replaceWith($html.find('#num_count'));
                    $('tr#paginate').replaceWith($html.find('tr#paginate'));
                    $('.pagination').replaceWith($html.find('.pagination'));
////////////////////////////////// here ////////////////////////////////

        },
```

**EXAMPLE:** [Yourself see](http://www.binboy.gigfa.com/admin/accommodation/show)

In example above please check row and click on DELETE to see it.

Comment: what should happen exactly? also you have multiple IDs in your html. the same id should only occur once

Answer (score 0):

**Here i tried to simulate your scenario
http://jsfiddle.net/yY2AS/1/**

your question was not very clear to me, anyway...

before makeing the `ajax request do

```
$this = $('.ser_form #paginate input:checkbox:checked').parent().parent();
```

then make the ajax call(i am guessing that the ajax call is to delete and update record)

in the success call back do

```
success: function(html){
            $this.fadeOut("slow");
           //rest of the code
```

Comment: you understand my mean correctly. i putting but don't work. ?

Comment: @Emma Winslet  see the link i have posted at the top of my answer that may help you to understand the problem

Comment: i have used `setTimeOut` function just to simulate the `ajax` call

Comment: if i disable `$('#num_count') & $('tr#paginate') & $('.pagination')` `fadeOut` worked. see you: [i they disable](http://www.binboy.gigfa.com/admin/accommodation/show)

Comment: i not want disable $('#num_count') & $('tr#paginate') & $('.pagination'). !?

Comment: @Emma Winslet very sorry it is very difficult to understand your requirement but now the fade out seems to be working :)