# problem with use of effect fadeOut.?

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [don't work 'fadeOut' If there is 'replaceWith'.?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7153079/dont-work-fadeout-if-there-is-replacewith)

I want after delete row(s) in table, for it row that deleted use of effect `fadeOute('slow')`, but it don't work in my code.(if not use of `.replaceWith()` it worked.)

[EXAMPLE](http://www.binboy.gigfa.com/admin/accommodation/show) => checked and clicke on DELETE

code:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        success: function(html){
            var $html = $(html);
////////////////////////////////// here ////////////////////////////////
                    $('.ser_form #paginate input:checkbox:checked').parent().parent().fadeOut("slow");

                    $('#num_count').replaceWith($html.find('#num_count'));
                    $('tr#paginate').replaceWith($html.find('tr#paginate'));
                    $('.pagination').replaceWith($html.find('.pagination'));
////////////////////////////////// here ////////////////////////////////

        },
```

Comment: You posted the same question yesterday...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the fadeOut first, than when it's completed, delete the element

```
element.fadeOut("slow", function(){
    $(this).remove();
});
```